# Codeigniter's is_unique doesn't work with multiple fields

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm making registration form, and I want fields `nick` and `e-mail` to be unique. I use form validation in controller:

> ```
>   $this->load->library('form_validation');
>     $this->form_validation->set_rules('nick', '<b>Nazwa użytkownika</b>', 'required|is_unique[users.nick]');
>     $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', '<b>Adres e-mail</b>', 'required|is_unique[users.mail]');
>     $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', '<b>Hasło</b>', 'required');
> ```

```
    $this->form_validation->set_message('is_unique', '%s jest już w bazie.');

    if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
        $data['submit'] = $this->users_model->CreateUser($this->input->post()); //submits data
        $this->load->view('contribute/emptyPage', $data); //loads view
    } else {
        $data['title'] = 'Załóż konto';
        $this->layout->view('account/create',$data);
    }
```

It works when I fill only one field, eq. `nick` or `mail`. When I fill the whole form, it processes without a problem. Whan can I do?

edit.

I found out that problem occures only when one or more of the fields have only numbers in it.

Comment: if i where you i would make a callback function

Comment: What version of CI are you using?

Comment: @LeventeNagy: callback function is the last option, I am not a fan of writing something that's already available.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your own [custom validation callback function](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks)

Comment: @Robert Because that is the only way, with in the confines of Codeigniter's form validation framework, to do what he wants to accomplish. If you have a better solution feel free to provide it, thats what SO is all about! :)

Comment: Depends what OP wants - when I first read the question I thought he wanted a username/email combination to be unique hence the custom callback function suggestion.  But if the two fields must be independently unique then there is no need to use one.

Comment: Custom callback function seems like an alternative. I never used is_unique myself but I don't see anywhere in the CI's user guide that you can use only one "is_unique" per form.

Comment: I don't see why I need to create a callback function. It's not a big problem, but it is reinventing the wheel.

Comment: If you read my last comment - I am saying you don't need to use a custom callback function. I orginally misread your question - as the combination of nick and email must be unique - for that you would need a custom function.  But if you want an unique nick and a unique email address then you don't need to use a custom function.

Answer (score 0):

I have created an [is_unique function here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14575165/validation-unique-field-in-codeigniter-with-2-index/46362569#46362569)

You can use it in 2 ways:

```
//is_unique[table_name.field_to_check.id_field_name.id_field_value] <-- unique 1 field only
//is_unique[table_name.field_to_check.id_field_name != 'id_field_value' and anotherIdName='theValue'] <-- custom where
```

hope it could be usefull for you