# Validation UNIQUE field in Codeigniter with 2 index

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, validation

In the Codeigniter Framework, I can validate an Unique field in the MYSQL Database using the "Form Validation Class". Exemple:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('form_field', 'form_label', 'is_unique[table.field]');
```

Work perfectly, but, I need validate a field from a table with 2 index. Exemple:

```
UNIQUE INDEX `id_aluno` (`id_aluno`, `ano`),
```

The Codeigniter Framework can do it natively?

Comment: Not sure if there is anything native, but what happens if you add the rule twice? `$this->form_validation->set_rules('form_field', 'form_label', 'is_unique[table.field1]', 'is_unique[table.field2]');`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that `CI` has built-in case for combined `PK` but I would use **callback_** like this: **but note that you have to send the second `PK` as extra and the rule should be applied on the first $PK see [callbacks](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks) for more info about that**

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('form_field', 'form_label', 'callback_combpk[$pk2]');
    public function combpk($pk1, $pk2)
        {
               $this->db->where('field1', $pk1);
               $this->db->where('field2', $pk2);
               $result = $this->db->get('table');
               if($result->num_rows() > 0)
               {
                  $this->form_validation->set_message('combpk','something'); // set your message
                  return false;
               }
               else{ return true;}

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules(
    'form_field', 
    'form_label', 
    'trima|is_unique[table1.field1],trim|required|is_unique[table.field2]');
```

use

```
'trima|is_unique[table1.field1],trim|required|is_unique[table.field2]'
```

in single code

Comment: That checks that each has a unique value in isolation, not as a combined index.

Answer (score 1):

Did not find the description of native support for this functionality in CodeIgniter. You can check after INSERT query the database error number. For example:

```
$last_id = $this->model->set();
if ($last_id === FALSE)
    if ($this->db->_error_number() == 1062)
        $this->data['message_error'] = 'Not unique.';
    else
        $this->data['message_error'] = 'Database error.';
```

This method has disadvantages, but certainly has an advantage - do not use additional SELECT query.

P.S. If several different composite unique indexes, then of course you can use `preg_match(<pattern_with_index_name>, $this->db->_error_message());`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are interested to my custom is_unique function.
here it is.

you can use it in 2 ways:

```
1. is_unique[table_name.field_to_check.id_field_name.id_field_value] //<-- unique 1 field only


2. is_unique[table_name.field_to_check.id_field_name != 'id_field_value' and anotherIdName='theValue'] //<-- custom where
```

Just save this code in a file, name it MY_Form_Validation.php, and place it under libraries directory. You can then put those is_unique

```
 public function is_unique($str, $field)
    {
        $result = true;
        try {
            if ($str) {//validate only if there's a value submitted
                $is_query = 0;

                $x = substr_count($field, '.'); //count of dots  
                //ex: is_unique[is_unique[$table_name.$field_name.$field_id!='$id' and 1=1]] 
                //ex: is_unique[$table_name.$field_name.id!='2' and name!='simson'] 
                if($x == 2) {
                    list($table, $field, $where) = explode('.', $field);
                    $is_unique = 0;

                    if ($where) {
                        $logos = "select * from $table where $field =? and $where ";
                    } else {
                        $logos = "select * from $table where $field =?  ";
                    }

                    $data = array($str);
                    $qq = $this->CI->db->query($logos, $data);
                    $is_query = 1;
                    $row = $qq->row();
                    $is_unique = !(bool)$row; //is_unique = (row == empty) 
                    $result = (bool)$is_unique;
                }
                else {
                    if ($x >= 3) {
                        list($table, $field, $id_field, $id_val) = explode('.', $field);
                        $is_unique = 0;
                        if ($id_field && $id_val) {
                            $logos = "select * from $table where $field =? and $id_field != '$id_val' ";
                        } else {
                            $logos = "select * from $table where $field =?  ";
                        }
                        $data = array($str);
                        $qq = $this->CI->db->query($logos, $data);
                        $is_query = 1;

                        $row = $qq->row();
                        if ($row) {
                            if ($row->id) {
                                if ($row->$id_field == $id_val) {
                                    $is_unique = 1; //means editing it self, allow it 
                                } else {
                                    //already exists with different id
                                }
                            } else {
                                //used for left join table
                            }
                        } else {
                            $is_unique = 1; //does not exists
                        }
                        $result = (bool)$is_unique;
                    }
                    else if ($x == 1) {
                        list($table, $field) = explode('.', $field);
                        $query = $this->CI->db->limit(1)->get_where($table, array($field => $str));
                        $is_query = 1;
                        $result = $query->num_rows() === 0;
                    }
                }

                if (is_log_query() && $is_query) {
                    $logos = "logos is_unique x==$x: " . $this->CI->db->last_query();
                    log_to_file($logos);
                } else {
                    $logos = "logos is_unique x==$x: NOT EXECUTED";
                    log_to_file($logos);
                }
            }

        }catch (Exception $e) {
            die($e->getTraceAsString());
        }
        return $result;
    }
```